# How do I force node to wait for aws promise to resolve?

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-s3, promise, aws-sdk

Trying to access a S3 bucket from a node.js express application. I'm trying to return the JSON file from the bucket in the form of a JSON object. Here's the code:

```
    let gets3 = function(file) {
        devs3();
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
            var params = {
                Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
                Key: file
            }
            var s3 = new aws.S3();
            try {
            s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
                var myfile = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
                resolve(myfile);
            });
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    }


module.exports = {


    fetchEvents : function(cata) {
        var myJson;
        switch (cata) {

            case "Pr":
                myJson = 'primaryEvents.json';

            case "Sc":
                myJson = 'secondaryEvents.json';

            case "Po":
                myJson = 'postEvents.json';
        }

        let gets3init = gets3(myJson);

        gets3init.then(function(file) {
            console.log('From Fetch Events: ' + JSON.stringify(file));
            return file;
        });

    }
}
```

devs3() just sets the S3 login information and runs aws.config.setPromisesDependancy. In my main app.js, I run fetchEvents("Pr") and then try and display it. In my console, it successfully displays the contents of the json file, however the application exists with a type error: `cannot read property 'n' of undefined`, where n is the name of the first element in the Json file. One thing to note is that this error displays in the console **before** the JSON file is printed, thereby showing that the function is not waiting for gets3 to finish and return the file. Is there anyway to force the application to wait (this happens on a page load) for promise to resolve?

Comment: Your `fetchEvents` must return a promise so that its caller can wait for it. No, you cannot block on it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a best confused what you mean @Bergi. What do you mean by 'block on it'?

Comment: "Block" means "force to wait synchronously". You cannot do that.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there any method at all then that I can ensure that the code waits for ```s3.getObject()``` to execute it's callback?

Comment: *Your code* (the `console.log('From Fetch Events: ' + JSON.stringify(file));` inside the `then` callback) already *does* wait for `s3.getObject()`. But `fetchEvents()` doesn't return a promise itself, so its caller cannot wait. Change that, and then change the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi for pointing me in the right direction and helping me get this answer. Essentially, I was using promises wrong from the start. I needed to return the promise from the `fetchEvents` function, not the data, and then use this in the calling code in order to only proceed once the promise has been resolve. 
**fetchEvents**

```
module.exports = {


    fetchEvents : function(cata) {
        var myJson;
        switch (cata) {

            case "Pr":
                myJson = 'primaryEvents.json';
                break;

            case "Sc":
                myJson = 'secondaryEvents.json';
                break;

            case "Po":
                myJson = 'postEvents.json';
                break;
        }

        return gets3(myJson);

    }
}
```

**Calling Code**

```
app.get('/PrEvents', function(req, res) {
    var myCata = req.path.replace('Events', '').replace('/', '');
    fetch(myCata).then(function(events) {
      res.render('pages/eventsShowTemp', {
        console.log(events);
      });
    });
  });
```